# My PC won't start up, what can I try?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting

My computer has been randomly restarting itself for the last couple of days. Sometimes it would stay on for hours before restarting, other times it wouldn't even get into Windows before restarting. Since yesterday it won't start at all. When I press the power button the fans starts spinning and the lights go on for perhaps half a second before shutting down again. I have tried taking out the graphic card and the rams with the problem persisting. The strange thing is that if I hold down both the start button and the restart button at the same time then the computer starts but will display nothing on the monitor.

How can I pinpoint the problem?

Comment: It would be better to take it in for servicing. It's very likely that it is a problem with the CPU.

Comment: @LDC3 CPU's don't break so easily, they actually don't, only when overheated. It's probably a problem with capacitors and if the OP isn't a superuser, he should take it to a service.

Answer (score 1):

This could be any number of problems.

Possibility 1: Your power supply could be fried. This is less likely though, because if it were a problem with your power supply, then the computer wouldn't come on at all.

Possibility 2: Your motherboard is broken. This is more likely. Because of the many components on a motherboard, if a single one stops working, then the whole thing stops working.

Possibility 3: RAM. This is also less likely, if the RAM stopped working, your computer would turn on, but it would simply do nothing.

Possibility 4: CPU heat-related damage. this is most likely. Sudden restarts and eventual startup failure are sure tail signs of CPU overheating. the only way to tell for sure is to take the Heatsink off the CPU and look for heat damage (Burn marks, warped chip-board, lack of Thermal Paste).

I can garuntee it is NOT your graphics card, even without a graphics card installed, a computer will startup just like normal, especially if you have an integrated graphics card as well.